# Row level security in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, row-level-security

Is there something new about row-level security in SQL Server 2012?

In 2008 and below the only way was using Views, in 2012 they announced [something](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522628.aspx) like `Row Level Security in Tabular Models`, does this have any relation to RLS over tables?

Are there any news on RLS in 2012 in general?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Row Level Security in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942301/implementing-row-level-security-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is still no support out of the box. There are a white paper, [Implementing Row- and Cell-Level Security in Classified Databases](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/mission-critical-operations/security-and-compliance.aspx) and an accompanying [toolkit](http://sqlserverlst.codeplex.com/) you can use to implement RLS, CLS based on labels, which were updated to cover SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks, saw that toolkits, but thought, maybe there's something new.. too bad